# pointer variable of class 'Entity' within class 'Component', gives errors even though 'Entity.h' has been included

Tags: c++, oop, entity

Okay So I'm making my own Entity Component System, and I'm trying to have an Entity pointer object within a Component class, but the object(variable) gives me a ton of errors, even though it has been included.

```
'Component.h'
#include "Entity.h"
class Component {

public:
Entity* ThisEntity;

}
```

That doesn't work, and gives me 76 errors inside 'Entity.h', all of which don't recognize my custom types(like Component, string, etc).
I usually use a global header file which has all the global variables, and includes everything necessary, like this:

```
'Public.h'

#ifndef Entity_h
#include "Entity.h" // Entity is include guarded
#endif
```

When i try to include 'Public.h' inside 'Component.cpp' it still gives me errors:

```
'Component.cpp'

#include "Public.h"
#include "Component.h" // The arrangement is correct, public before component but this still doesn't work
```

When I hover over the pointer variable "Entity* ThisEnt" it shows me "Entity Class", so it recognizes it but it still gives me 76 errors.

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: @theVoid what do you mean ? I'm using VS2015, and Visual C++.

Comment: Do you have all the files in the same project?

Comment: @theVoid Yes I do

Comment: Have you tried to instead use '#pragma once' in the header file?

Comment: From your description, it looks like you try to access Entity from a Component and a Component from an Entity.


If all you need is a pointer, have you tried only forward declaring the class Entity in Component.h instead of including the file?

Comment: @Bhargava I'm not sure, but I need an Entity variable that keeps track of the Entity in which this component has been added, i basically need an Entity pointer to be carried to 'Component' children

Comment: @Stephen In which header file ? and why use pragma once instead of include guards ?

Comment: @kooldart If you only want a pointer, add 'class Entity;' in Component.h and include Entity.h in Component.cpp.

Comment: @Stephen Forward declaring Entity seemed to fix the problem, thanks

Comment: @kooldart glad to hear it

Comment: @kooldart Since my comment seemed to be correct, I have put it as an answer for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not refer to header files from each other as it creates a cyclical dependency. 
You can break that dependency by forward declaring one of the classes you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaring the class 'Entity' before the class 'Component' seemed to fix the issue.